# Concatenate urls based on result of two columns

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I would like to first take out of the string in the first column parenthesis which I can do with:

```
awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}'
```

Then, concatenate it with the second column to create a URL with the following format:

```
"https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/"[firstcolumn stripped out of parenthesis]-[secondcolumn].tar.gz
```

With input like:

```
Admin Toolbar (admin_toolbar)           8.x-2.5       
Entity Embed (entity_embed)             8.x-1.2       
Views Reference Field (viewsreference)  8.x-2.0-beta2 
Webform (webform)                       8.x-5.28
```

Data from the first line would create this URL:

```
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-2.5.tar.gz
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and  then [edit] your question to fix the formatting of your sample input, output, and code. You've been a member of this forum for 10+ years now, it's long past time to learn how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, Ed for your advice.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sure you'll get some good answers as soon as you format your question. See other questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples if you're not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```sh
sed 's!^[^(]*(\([^)]*\))[[:space:]]*\(.*\)!https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/\1-\2.tar.gz!' input.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps add comment like: You want something like `'s/.*(\(.*\)) *(.*)/url\1-\2.tar.tgz/'`. Making this work requires some changes, resulting in ...

Answer (score 1):

If a file `a` has your input, you can try this:

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '
  { 
    split($3,parts," *") 
    printf "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/%s-%s.tar.gz\n", $2, parts[2]
  }' a 
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-2.5.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/entity_embed-8.x-1.2.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/viewsreference-8.x-2.0-beta2.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/webform-8.x-5.28.tar.gz
```

The trick is to split the third field  ($3).  Based on your field separator ( `-F'[()]'`), the third field contains everything after the right paren.  So, split can be used to get rid of all the spaces.  I probably should have searched for an awk "trim" equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In the example data, the second last column seems to contain the part with the parenthesis that you are interested in, and the value of the last column.

If that is always the case, you can remove the parenthesis from the second last column, and concat the hyphen and the last column.

```
awk '{
gsub(/[()]/, "", $(NF-1))
printf "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/%s-%s.tar.gz%s", $(NF-1), $NF, ORS
}' file
```

Output

```
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/admin_toolbar-8.x-2.5.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/entity_embed-8.x-1.2.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/viewsreference-8.x-2.0-beta2.tar.gz
https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/webform-8.x-5.28.tar.gz
```

---

Another option with a regex and `gnu awk`, using [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) and 2 capture groups to capture what is between the parenthesis and the next field.

```
awk 'match($0, /^[^()]*\(([^()]+)\)\s+(\S+)/, ary) {
printf "https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/%s-%s.tar.gz%s", ary[1], ary[2], ORS
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, If my output is not in file, it's on stdout, can I pipe this command? or is better to save the output in file then run the awk command?

Comment: @tleo you can pipe the output to awk, see https://ideone.com/iK2nmN

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*(#https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/#;s/)\s*/-/;s/\s*$/.tar.gz/' file
```

Pattern match, replacing the unwanted parts by the required strings.

N.B. The use of the `#` as a delimiter for the substitution command to avoid inserting back slashes into the literal replacement.

The above solution could be ameliorated into:

```
sed -E 's#.*\((.*)\)\s*(\S*).*#https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/\1-\2.tar.gz#' file
```